# Python lists indexes

Tags: python, list

i have a litle question since iam new to python, i came from php and in php iam able to define array with explicit indexes

```
 array(
         "Index1" => array(),
         "Index2" => array()
         );
```

Iam wondering if iam able to do the same thing with lists in python, for example

```
["Index1" => [], "Index2" => []]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about dictionary in python.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

```
>>> d = {"Index1": [], "Index2": []}
>>> d["Index1"]
[]
```

or

```
>>> d = dict(Index1=[], Index2=[])
```

Comment: I think `collections.OrderedDict` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You may be right. The difference is that collections.OrderedDict is ordered, wheres dictionary is not.

Answer (score 0):

The *equivalent* would be an ordered dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([
    ('Index1', []),
    ('Index2', [])
])
```

Although order is rarely used, so a regular dictionary should be just fine in most cases:

```
d = {
    'Index1': [],
    'Index2': []
}
```